# Add text and line to an `image()` in graphics

Tags: r, plot

I generated an image in R from two-dimensional data - `x`.

```
graphics::image(ifelse(drop(x)!=0, x, NA))
```

I would like to add a text and a line to the image.

I attempted `text(10, 10, "testing")` and `segments(5, 10, 20, 25)`, but neither the text nor the line was displayed.

Comment: `image()` typically rescales everything to the 0-1 range. `Try text(.5, .5, "testing")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @MrFlick mentioned, `image()` rescales values to the 0-1 range.

See below example:

```
#dummy data
set.seed(123)
x <- matrix(runif(100),nrow=10)

#plot
image(x)

#add text and a line
text(0.1,0.1,"text")
segments(0.5,0.1,0.2,0.25)
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me! I had to place my axes back on the image first though. threw me off using `xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n'`