# R: segments can not be displayed in a video file

Tags: r, video, text

I attempted to create a video file in R using the "animation" package.  Each frame is formed by a two-dimensional matrix (graphics::images) and a text and a segment are also added to the frame. Prior to creating the video, the text and segment have been tested, following the following post; when putting in the video file, the text and segment can no longer be seen.

[Add text and line to an `image()` in graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246467/add-text-and-line-to-an-image-in-graphics)

```
saveVideo({
par(mar = c(5, 0.2, 1, 2), mgp = c(3, 1, 0), tcl = -0.3, cex.axis = 1, 
cex.lab = 0.8, cex.main = 1)
ani.options(interval = 0.6, nmax = 50, ani.height=0.2, ani.width=0.3)

for (FrameNo in c(1:5)){
X <- Y[,,FrameNo]
graphics::image(ifelse(drop(X)!=0, X, NA),
                col=rgb(0,1,1,alpha), add=TRUE)

segments(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, col="white", lwd=3)
text(0.05, 0.18, "testing", col="white")
}  
}, video.name = FileN, other.opts = "-b 300k")
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution - not the most straightforward one, but it works...

1. Create individual frames as PNG files
2. use ffmpeg to generate a video
   file using these individual PNG files.